# Making an AJAX request to a Django view that may require a redirect?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, redirect

**Introduction**

I am getting an error when trying to request a particular Django view from AJAX. This view redirects the user if they have not yet authorized the site with Google. I believe that the problem lies in the fact that I am trying to perform the redirect from "within" a view requested by AJAX. Read on for more information, and thanks in advance for your help!

**Background information**

I wrote a view in Django called `export_to_drive` that uses the Google Drive API and returns some JSON.

```
@gauth_required(scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file')
def export_to_drive(request, credential, sheet_id):
    """
    Export a sheet to Google Drive.
    """
    http = credential.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = build('drive', 'v3', http=http)

    # ...

    new_file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                      media_body=media,
                                      fields='webViewLink').execute()

    return jsonResponse(new_file)
```

This view requires the user to give the site permission to add files to their Google Drive on their behalf. In order to ensure that the user has authorized the site with Google, I wrote a decorator called `gauth_required`.

```
def gauth_required(scope):
    """
    Decorator that requires the user to authenticate
    with Google and authorize the site to act on their behalf.
    If the user has already authenticated, it will call the wrapped function
    with the kwarg `credential` set to the obtained credentials.
    If not, it will start the OAuth 2.0 flow.
    At the moment, only used for sheets.views.export_to_drive.
    """
    def wrapper(func):
        @login_required
        @wraps(func)
        def inner(request, *args, **kwargs):
            storage = Storage(CredentialsModel, 'id',
                              request.user, 'credential')
            credential = storage.get()

            if credential is None or credential.invalid:
                request.session['next_view'] = request.path
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/gauth?scope={}'.format(scope))

            kwargs['credential'] = credential
            return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return inner
    return wrapper
```

As you can (hopefully) see, this decorator checks to see if there is a stored credential object for the given user and if not, it will start the OAuth 2.0 authentication flow to obtain one. As I do not believe it is relevant to the question (and in an effort to refrain from scaring away potential answerers with enormous amounts of code), I'm choosing to not show you the code for the flow. The only real important detail to know about the it is that it requires several redirects (this will come up later).

**The problem**

The `export_to_drive` view is being accessed via a jQuery AJAX call from some client-side Javascript.

```
function exportToDrive() {
    $.post("/api/sheets/" + sjs.current.id + "/export_to_drive", function(data) {
        if ("error" in data) {
            sjs.alert.message(data.error.message);
        } else {
            sjs.alert.message("Source Sheet exported to Google Drive.<br><br><a href='" + data.webViewLink + "'>Open in Google Drive &raquo;</a>");
        }
    })
}
```

When I attempt to click on the UI element that this function is bound to, I get the following error in the console if there is no credential on-file for the signed in user.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?state=zdsChtkBh_T7IoSyl5cpVDoxNDY…e=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive.file&access_type=offline. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

When I go directly to the `export_to_drive` endpoint in my browser, everything works dandy, regardless of whether the credential is retrieved from storage or created by the OAuth 2.0 flow. Therefore, I have a hunch that the problem lies in needing to perform a redirect to complete the authorization flow from within an AJAX request.

**The question(s)**

- Is it possible to perform a redirect from a requested AJAX url? If not, is there a good way to refactor this code to make it work without needing to do that?
- Has anyone dealt with this or something similar to this before?
- Is my suspicion completely off-base and something else entirely is causing this error?

Comment: You could always create some kind of Error response which is used to redirect using JavaScript. You're correct in your assumption that you can't handle the redirect in Python, if you're doing an AJAX request.

Comment: @rnevius Wow thanks for the fast response! Could you explain in more detail what you mean by "some kind of Error response which is used to redirect using JavaScript?" Would this be an "automatic" redirect, or would the user need to click a link? If you could flesh your comment out into an answer it would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem while trying to sync some contacts on google and start the whole process from the client side. Managed to work around it by returning the redirect url (instead of doing a `HttpResponseRedirect`) and redirecting from jquery.

So, instead of `return HttpResponseRedirect('/gauth?scope={}'.format(scope))` you could return a json: `{'redirect_url': '/gauth?scope={}'.format(scope)}` and on the client side:

```
if ("error" in data) {
    sjs.alert.message(data.error.message);
} else if ("redirect_url" in data) {
    // if you're returning to the same page, you would need to post to the export api again
    window.location.replace(data.response.redirect_url);
} else {
    sjs.alert.message("Source Sheet exported to Google Drive.<br><br><a href='" + data.webViewLink + "'>Open in Google Drive &raquo;</a>");
}
```

A problem still remains: after you redirect to oauth and the user authorizes the operation he will get back to your page and you should try to export again. In order to figure out that you need to try again you could:

- set some cookies when you redirect and check for them when the page loads (after authorization)
- pass in a GET parameter to the url oauth will use to return after authorization (you should be able to modify that url in python, verify the GET parameter on the client side and restart the export process)

I started working with python/django a few months ago so I'm not sure this is the best solution (another one would be to do the whole oauth process on the client side - never tried it) but I hope it helps. If you managed to solve the problem in another way, I would be grateful if you could share some insight.